# jumping to symbols using ctags within vim

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

I'm using `ctags`, `cscope` & `vim` and whenever I am on a symbol and hit `Ctrl+]`, I get presented a choice, which file I want to jump to, which is fine only that the choice looks like:

```
  # pri kind tag                                      file
  1 F   f    switch_wan_mpls_infrastructure_cc_event  /home/ron/src/NextGen/trunk/FW/src/rtos_core/jpax_switch/api/src/infrastructure/switch_wan_mpls_infrastructure.c
               switch_wan_mpls_infrastructure_cc_event (int no_companion) {
  2 F   f    switch_wan_mpls_infrastructure_cc_event  /home/ron/src/NextGen/trunk/FW/src/rtos_core/jpax_switch/api/src/infrastructure/switch_wan_mpls_infrastructure.c
               switch_wan_mpls_infrastructure_cc_event (int no_companion) {
```

exactly the same file is listed twice. Why is this and how can I ignore this (if duplicate)?

Comment: Not sure if relevant: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/5963/exuberant-ctags-duplicate-tags-problem

Answer (score 0):

I  have been able to resolve the problem with the script from: https://coderwall.com/p/khzioa/rebuild-cscope-database it works like a charm!